# what to do when a you next employer ask you about your previous employer's contacts?

Tags: recruitment, resignation, company-policy

I hate working in my company, the managers were really stressful and the environment was really dark so i had some problems with them: once the manager started yelling at me for no reason, the scheduling is always overloaded and with such environment i couldn't work properly but i have tried my best, the salary is weak, the type of work is bad, when i leave after finishing my 8 hours they tell me that they are not happy with it, ...

So i have started searching for a new job and i found one in a big operator, unfortunately the manager figured out where i was going and they blocked my candidature **(it doesn't matter how i knew, but i am 100% sure)**. And now i got recently hired by another company, i have signed the contract and i will start working next month. They gave me a form that includes a field "contacts of your previous bosses" and i preferred to not fill these fields because the company that i was working with is hell and it's bosses are so mean that they could do anything nonhuman to make you suffer because you decided to quit.

1. After that they called me asking for the contacts , so i tried explaining that my boss tried questioning me many times to know where i was going and i didn't wanted to answer until i got fed up and told him that i am going to study in Europe so it wouldn't be a good idea to contact them and ask them about me. this could influence their behavior with me and they could not give me my last month's payment
2. i told them also that this company already did cancel my friend's application in another company **(but as i told you this really happened to me)**

so they told me "this is a formality that should be done, you can write us a mail telling the reason why you don't want us to contact them now and may be we will ask them a month after"

what should i do , i am confused ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your new employer is giving you a chance. You'll just have to trust them. If you don't comply and give up those names, you have no chance at all with the new company.

You can't prevent the HR of your new company from doing due diligence and contacting your former bosses. If you even try, your credibility is shot and you're done for. What you can do is express in writing your concern that your bosses have a history of trying to get back at those employees who left. Try to come up with references other than your bosses, especially former co-workers who attained high positions after they left the company. Don't write a book. Make it short - off the top of my head, not more than one paragraph of at most four to five sentences. Stick to what they do and how they act, not what you think of that. No editorializing. No rant. No temper tantrums. You are the adult in your narrative, so write and speak like one.

Comment: +1 for coming up with coworkers as references. Most companies will be fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered a while ago, but I think a few more things are to consider in this position.

First of all, try to always talk neutrally or positively of your current/pass employers. People hiring you do not want to be badly talked of in the event that this does not go how you want it to, and they only have a few moments to judge your character.

Also, most jobs will require either proof of employment or current employer's contacts, sometimes it is only to confirm your employment and time there.

I think in this situation, providing the right information to the new employer with some context could be benefiting to you.

Try to write it in such a way that shows that you are not a bad employee, perhaps by mentionning how long you have been working there in the email (Surely they would'nt keep you for 3 years if you were a terrible employee!).

You could also ask a previous employer for a letter of recommendation, I doubt that can hurt.

> Hello,
>
> as requested, here are the contact information of my current employer.
>   As we discussed on the phone, I am not leaving on the best of terms
>   with Mr.X due to personnal circumstances, but they will be able to
>   confirm that I worked there from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM-DD.
>
> Furthermore, I took the liberty to ask a former employer for a character reference letter, which I added as attachment.
>   [...]